# Class inherits tkinter.Tk(), how to access objects?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, tkinter

I am using this code, which I  found online, to set up my Tkinter GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("600x400")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.test = " this is a test"

print(XXXX.test)

App().mainloop()
```

Now I would like to acces the "self.test" from somewhere else in the program (see: XXXX.test).
-How can I achieve this?

I'm very new to object oriented programming and I am a little bit irritated by what my code above is actually doing
-Have I created one instance by inheriting the tkinter.Tk() class? If yes what is the "self" of this instance?

Comment: You need to create `App` instance: `app = App()`. Then you can access to `test` variable: `app.test`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght well, he *is* creating an `App` instance, but he's not saving a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save a reference to the instance of `App`, and then access the element from that instance. For example:

```
app = App()
print(app.test)
```

> -Have I created one instance by inheriting the tkinter.Tk() class? If yes what is the "self" of this instance?

No, you don't create instances by inheriting. You create an instance when you call the class. In the above code, `app = App()` is what creates the instance. Inside the class, `self` is the same as `app` outside of the class. They both refer to the single instance that has been created.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my problem. Still I have a new Problem now. When I Start my Programm there are 2 Tkinter windows opening. Do you know why?

Comment: @Maxim: You have to replace `App().mainloop()` with `app.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you're working with classes, it would be a good OOP practice to add a method to the class, that returns the variable you need. Example:

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 10
    def get_var(self):
        return self.var
obj = Sample()
print(obj.get_var())  #prints 10
```

Comment: Why do you need getter there? If you've implemented getter, why you haven't use property?

Comment: @OlvinRoght what property?

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) property.

Comment: Makes sense. I was just providing a simple example to OP, using simple OOP concepts. This method is readable and works straight off the bat

Comment: It's more complicated then just use `obj.var`.

Comment: Using a method instead of direct access is usually considered a better practice

Comment: In that particular case there's no reason to use getter. Anyway, if you want to show how to use properties, use built-in `property`.

Comment: @Abhinav Actually property is a getter function, not direct access.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you to access the test:

```
def __repr__(self):
        print(self.test)
```

Comment: Why do you need to override `__repr__()` if you can just access variable by it's name on class instance.

Comment: It is class representation we can print any variable in the init

Comment: Yes, it is, but you should not use it for printing anything.